# how to set default button Html javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have 2 buttons in one form:

```
<input type="text" id="txtSearch" maxlength="250" placeholder="Enter Search" style="height: 42px; padding-right: 36px;" runat="server" />
<button type="submit" onserverclick="btnSearch_Click" id="btnSearch" runat="server"></button>

<input type="text" id="_searchKeyword" maxlength="250" placeholder="Search Term" style="height: 42px; padding-right: 36px;" runat="server" />
            <button type="submit" onserverclick="SearchButton" id="btnSearchNoResult" runat="server">
            </button>
```

My JavaScript:

```
$("#txtSearch").keyup(function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    $("#btnSearch").click();
  }
}); 
$("#_searchKeyword").keyup(function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    $("#btnSearchNoResult").click();
  }
});
```

if I type on _searchKeyword input text, and then press Enter button, I get the value of txtSearch input text. How can I get the value of _searchKeyword input text with enter press not value of txtSearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add something like the code below to each of your inputs..

For the txtSearch...

```
onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13) doTxtSearch()"
```

For the searchKeyword...

```
onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13) doSearchKeyword()"
```

Full code changes below....

```
    <input type="text" id="txtSearch" maxlength="250" placeholder="Enter Search" style="height: 42px; padding-right: 36px;" runat="server" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13) doTxtSearch()"/>
    <button type="submit" onserverclick="btnSearch_Click" id="btnSearch" runat="server"></button>

    <input type="text" id="_searchKeyword" maxlength="250" placeholder="Search Term" style="height: 42px; padding-right: 36px;" runat="server" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13) doKeywordSearch()"/>
    <button type="submit" onserverclick="SearchButton" id="btnSearchNoResult" runat="server">
    </button>


    function doKeywordSearch()
    {
        //do Keyword Search stuff here
    }

    function doTxtSearch()
    {
        //do Text Search stuff here
    }
```

Comment: in the searchKeyword `onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13) doSearchKeyword()"` and js 
`function doSearchKeyword(){
        $("#btnSearchNoResult").click();
    }`

Comment: @beginerdeveloper - that is not where it needs to be. Ill edit my answer so you will understand.

Comment: i did it but form not submit just refresh the page btnSearchNoResult not working

Comment: @beginerdeveloper - what does your new code look like, please post changes or I cannot determine what is wrong. Usually when it just refreshes the page there is a JavaScript error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75888/discussion-between-beginerdeveloper-and-commonknowledge).